# Is there a way to set in devexpress grid: some rows are read only while the others are editable?

Tags: grid, devexpress, row, readonly

Hi
Is there a way to set the grid property so that some rows are readonly but others are editable?
e.g. a grid with column 1, column2, and column3.
if column1's value is "Red", then the whole row is readonly, is column1's value is other values except Red, it is editable. How could I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the GridView's [ShowingEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShowingEditortopic) event.  I.e. you should just set the e.Cancel parameter to true if you want to prevent a certain cell from being edited.  For more details, please refer to the [How to Conditionally Prevent Editing for Individual Grid Cells](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=A249)

Comment: I see the ValidateRow event and it seems it could help validate my columns. But I want to know when this event will be fired. Is there any detailed document talking about each event and when they fire?

Comment: All our controls and their public API is described in the documentation.  Its online version is available at: http://documentation.devexpress.com.  Also, the ValidateRow event is fired when the end-user edited a row and EndCurrentEdit method of the CurrencyManager is called.  This method can be called directly by pressing the EmbeddedNavigator's EndEdit button or changing the current focused row in the grid.